# Iterating a list of Pandas dataframes / reshaping dataframe with .unstack

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe with a DatetimeIndex:

```
                          X
timestamp                    
2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.788500
2013-01-01 00:30:00  0.761525
2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.751850
2013-01-01 01:30:00  0.746445
2013-01-01 02:00:00  0.688677
```

and I am using `unstack` to reshape it with half-hourly intervals as the columns, and dates as the rows - as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319929/reshape-pandas-dataframe-with-datetimeindex-to-make-grid).

```
df.index = [df.index.date, df.index.hour + df.index.minute / 60]
df = df['X'].unstack()
df.head()
              0.0       0.5       1.0       1.5       2.0       2.5   \
2013-01-01  0.788500  0.761525  0.751850  0.746445  0.688677  0.652226   
2013-01-02  0.799029  0.705590  0.661059  0.627001  0.606560  0.592116   
2013-01-03  0.645102  0.597785  0.563410  0.516707  0.495896  0.492416   
2013-01-04  0.699592  0.649553  0.598019  0.576290  0.561023  0.537802   
2013-01-05  0.782781  0.706697  0.645172  0.627405  0.605972  0.583536
```

All good. 
BUT I now want to carry out the same procedure for a number of dataframes. Initially, I'm using 2:

```
for df in [df1,df2]:
        df.index = [df.index.date, df.index.hour + df.index.minute / 60]
        df = df['X'].unstack()
```

The reindexing works, but the reshaping does not:

```
df1.head()

                      X
2013-01-01 0.0  0.788500
           0.5  0.761525
           1.0  0.751850
           1.5  0.746445
           2.0  0.688677
```

I think maybe I need some equivalent of `inplace` so the unstacked dataframes are passed back to `df1` and `df2`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem cause

You need to check how assignment works in Python. This [talk](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#plummeting-cliff) by Brandon Rhodes is pretty enlightening.

When you do `df = df['X'].unstack()` you assign to `df` the unstacked version of `df1` or `df2`, depending on the iteration, so you have 2 options

## Solution

- Do it inplace, but there doesn't seem to be an inplace [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
- Keep another reference to the unstacked version and assign `df1` and `df2` to these

This can be done with either a tuple, list or a dict.

### Extract the reshaping

The easiest would be to extract the operation itself to a seperate method

```
def my_reshape(df):
    df_copy = df.copy() # so as to leave the original DataFrame intact
    df_copy.index = [df.index.date, df.index.hour + df.index.minute / 60]
    return df_copy['X'].unstack()
```

#### as a tuple

```
df1, df2 = tuple(my_reshape(df) for df in (df1, df2))
```

#### variant with a dict

```
df_dict = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2}
for key, df in df_dict.items():
    df_dict[key] = my_reshape(df)
```

and if you need them outside of the dict afterwards

```
df1 = df_dict['df1']
df2 = df_dict['df2']
```